# How to inject weight into list of dplyr summarise name-value pairs?

Tags: r, parsing, dplyr, tidyeval

I want to write a generalized `weighted_summarise()` function that will automatically parse and transform user-invoked function calls of the form:

```
data %>% weighted_summarise(weights, a = sum(b), c = mean(d))
```

into an actual call that delegates to `dplyr::summarise`

```
data %>% dplyr::summarise(a = sum(weights * b), c = mean(weights * d))
```

Here, `a` and `c` are new columns to be created inside the reduced data, and `b`, `d` and `weights` are existing columns in `data`.

Ideally, I want my to call my function exactly as I would a "native" `dplyr::summarise`, but with an extra `weights` argument that gets sprinkled into each aggregation function.

```
weighted_summarise <- function(data, weights, ...) {
   data %>% dplyr::summarise(
       # how to manipulate the ... and inject the weights in each name-value pair?
   )
}
```

**Question** How can I manipulate the ellipsis so that the `weights` will be injected into every name-value pair in the appropriate place? I want to somehow capture an AST and walk it and manipulate it systematically.

Comment: Do you want the weights be a vector same length of `a` and `b` or just scalar ?

Comment: @TemplateRex Regarding the new names in your example, is it just random a, c?  Perhaps `weighted_summarise <- function(data, ..., weights) {
      v1 <- map_chr(ensyms(...), ~ rlang::as_string(.x));
      data %>%
          summarise(across(all_of(v1), ~ sum(weights * .x), .names = "{.col}_new")) 
  
       }`

Comment: @TemplateRex i modified the code I posted in the comments to actually pass a key/value pair and then use the key as the new column name.  Hope it helps

Comment: @TemplateRex Thanks, I deleted my answer as it was not the one you wanted.  You wanted to evaluate the expression you are passing

Comment: I guess the easiest would be to `paste` the `...` elements with the `"data %>% summarise(", ...` and then use `eval/parse_expr

Comment: I meant `weighted_summarise <- function(data, ..., weights) {
      weights <- rlang::as_string(rlang::ensym(weights));
     
     v1 <- purrr::map_chr(rlang::enexprs(...), ~ stringr::str_replace(rlang::as_label(.x), "\\(", function(x) stringr::str_c("(", weights, "*")));
   eval(rlang::parse_expr(stringr::str_c("data %>% summarise(", stringr::str_c(names(v1), v1, sep = "=", collapse = ", "), ")")))
   
       };
       
       data %>% weighted_summarise(a = sum(b), c = mean(d), weights = weights)`

Comment: @TemplateRex i made the correction on the solution posted.  Hope it helps. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one option to interpolate the 'weights' into expression passed in `...` by converting the multiple expressions into a single string and parse it to evaluate

```
weighted_summarise <- function(data, weights, ...) {
      weights <- rlang::as_string(rlang::ensym(weights))
     
     v1 <- purrr::map_chr(rlang::enexprs(...), 
   ~ stringr::str_replace(rlang::as_label(.x), "\\(",
     function(x) stringr::str_c("(", weights, "*")))
   eval(rlang::parse_expr(stringr::str_c("data %>% 
      summarise(", stringr::str_c(names(v1), v1, sep = "=", 
          collapse = ", "), ")")))
   
       }
```

-testing

```
> data %>%
     weighted_summarise(weights, a = sum(b), c = mean(d))
# A tibble: 1 × 2
      a     c
  <dbl> <dbl>
1 -2.95  1.13

# testing with the original summarise code outside the function
> data %>% 
    dplyr::summarise(a = sum(weights * b), c = mean(weights * d))
# A tibble: 1 × 2
      a     c
  <dbl> <dbl>
1 -2.95  1.13
```

#### data

```
data <- structure(list(b = c(-0.545880758366027, 0.536585304107612, 0.419623148618683, 
-0.583627199210279, 0.847460017311944, 0.266021979364892, 0.444585270360416, 
-0.466495123565759, -0.848370043948898, 0.00231194241576697), 
    d = c(-1.31690812429962, 0.598269112694685, -0.7622143703459, 
    -1.42909030324076, 0.332244449013422, -0.469060687608488, 
    -0.334986793584065, 1.53625215550584, 0.609994533253692, 
    0.51633569843567), weights = 1:10), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Comment: @TemplateRex not sure how you are passing the values in `...`  I showed two ways - one with alist and another with list

Comment: @TemplateRex Regarding the sum and mean, I was thinking both as sum.  Sorry, my mistake

Comment: @TemplateRex Suppose you are passing more than two columns, how does it differentiate which one goes for sum and mean

Comment: @TemplateRex If you can show in your post how you would call the function, it would make it easier

Comment: @TemplateRex okay, got it.  You want something with parse_expr then

Comment: Pasting strings together and parsing them is much less robust than creating expressions directly, e.g. with `call()`, `call2()`, or with `bquote()` or `expr()`.

Answer (score 1):

I would not use a metaprogramming approach. Instead, I'd create a special data mask with columns bound to *promises* (to avoid doing unnecessary multiplications eagerly) that multiply the columns by the weights. This would be much more robust, I think it'd work in virtually all cases.

Edit: example as requested:

```r
library(rlang)

data <- mtcars
weights <- seq_len(nrow(data))

env <- env()
purrr::imap(data, function(x, nm) env_bind_lazy(env, "{nm}" := weights * x))

env_print(env)
#> <environment: 0x12115aa58>
#> Parent: <environment: global>
#> Bindings:
#> • drat: <lazy>
#> • vs: <lazy>
#> • hp: <lazy>
#> • am: <lazy>
#> • disp: <lazy>
#> • cyl: <lazy>
#> • carb: <lazy>
#> • mpg: <lazy>
#> • qsec: <lazy>
#> • wt: <lazy>
#> • gear: <lazy>

env$vs
#>  [1]  0  0  3  4  0  6  0  8  9 10 11  0  0  0  0  0  0 18 19 20 21
#> [22]  0  0  0  0 26  0 28  0  0  0 32
```

Comment: Could you outline a code example how to do this?

Comment: I've added a small example but I don't know how you'd connect it to dplyr. I don't think we've planned for users to supply their own data mask. I'm just pointing out what would be a better approach for the task.